# Assign a variable in R using another variable

Tags: r, variables, escaping

I have to run 10's of different permutations with same structure but different base names for the output. to avoid having to keep replacing the whole character names within each formula, I was hoping to great a variable then use paste function to assign the variable to the name of the output..

Example:

```
var<-"Patient1"
(paste0("cells_", var, sep="") <- WhichCells(object=test, expression = test > 0, idents=c("patient1","patient2"))
```

The expected output would be a variable called "cells_Patient1"
Then for subsequent runs, I would just copy and paste these 2 lines and change var <-"Patient1" to var <-"Patient2"
[please note that I am oversimplifying the above step of WhichCells as it entails ~10 steps and would rather not have to replace "Patient1" by "Patient2" using Search and Replaced

Unfortunately, I am unable to crate the variable "cells_Patient1" using the above command. I am getting the following error:

> Error in variable(paste0("cells_", var, sep = "")) <-
>   WhichCells(object = test,  :    target of assignment expands to
>   non-language object

Browsing stackoverflow, I couldn't find a solution. My understanding of the error is that R can't assign an object to a variable that is not a constant. Is there a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Use `assign` like this:

```
var <- "Patient1"
assign(paste0("cells_", var), 3)
cells_Patient1
## [1] 3
```

**2) environment** This also works.

```
e <- .GlobalEnv
e[[ paste0("cells_", var) ]] <- 3
cells_Patient1
```

**3) list** or it might be better to make these variables into a list:

```
cells <- list()
cells[[ var ]] <- 3
cells[[ "Patient1" ]]
## [1] 3
```

Then we could easily iterate over all such variables.  Replace `sqrt` with any suitable function.

```
lapply(cells, sqrt)
## $Patient1
## [1] 1.732051
```

Comment: In regards to 1) assign and 2) environment, I got the same following error Error in paste0("cells_", var) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character' . As for list, it may not work for me as I have multiple commands for each variable that may make it complicated.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to define `var`.  `var` is also an R function to compute the variance.  You can see from the reproducible code in the answer and the output shown there that all three do work.  If you are really stuck I suggest you cut down the problem to something reproducible so we can copy and paste it into R and see what the problem is.  See the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.