# For loop with dynamic input

Tags: r

I am trying to create a dynamic input that I can easily change that will be used inside a for loop. Inside a for loop that I am using, there is a variable, let's call it `b`, that is used multiple times, and every time I want to slightly change the value stored in `b`, I have to go through and find each instance of `b` and change it. I am hoping to create an input outside of the for loop that I can use to update `b` inside the for loop.

This is a very simplified example of what I am currently doing.

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE)))
for (i in c(1:nrow(df))){
  nm <- i
  if (nm == nrow(df)) {
    next
  } else {
    x <- df[c((nm):(nm+1)),]
    b <- x$X1[1]
    print(b > x$X2[2])
  }
}
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to do, however, in this example the input does not work because dateframe `x` is not yet created. Some more examples of the inputs could be `b <- x$X1[2]`, `b <- x$X2[1]`, `b <- x$X3[2]`, etc

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE)))

##input

b <- x$X1[1]

###

for (i in c(1:nrow(df))){
  nm <- i
  if (nm == nrow(df)) {
    next
  } else {
    x <- df[c((nm):(nm+1)),]
    print(b > x$X2[2])
  }
}
```

I was looking at this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57454085/assign-a-variable-in-r-using-another-variable) and it looks like there is a way to achieve what I am trying to do, however, in the post, they assign a value to the variable. In my example, the value stored in `b` will change in every iteration of the for loop so this method will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like essentially you want to delay the evaluation of the expression for `b`. As written, `x$X1[1]` will be evaluated (or at least attempted to be) when `b` is defined. You can mark it as an expression and evaluate it later. There are some base functions for this but I find `rlang` often easier to use

```
##input

b <- rlang::expr(x$X1[1])

###

for (i in c(1:nrow(df))){
  nm <- i
  if (nm == nrow(df)) {
    next
  } else {
    x <- df[c((nm):(nm+1)),]
    print(rlang::eval_bare(b) > x$X2[2])
  }
}
```